# VS2010 Crashes closing specific project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a "Website Project" (as opposed to an ASP.NET Web Application) which we received from another company as part of an acquisition.

In general it works fine, however every time I close the project ("File" -> "Close Project" or just "File" -> "Exit"), the IDE crashes.

If I create a new project this doesn't happen, and it doesn't happen for any other project/solution file I have handy.

The other information I have that might be useful is that this project may have stared out as a VS2008 project, and previously it was under Microsoft source control (it's under Subversion now).

Comment: Im talking about all of your other questions..not my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya I had a project like that once.  Chances are there are 1001 possible reasons.  Just start a new website project, copy over your source files, and cross your fingers.  It's not worth trying to figure it out, since it works fine otherwise.

Comment: If it comes from vs 2008 to vs2010 there is a bug in the ide regarding this see the link I posted.

Answer (score 1):

This is a reported VS bug from 2008 to vs 2010.

Here is a direct link: http://connectppe.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/577369/vs2010-crashes-when-closing-project-or-ide

Comment: That may or may not be the issue.  Microsoft was unable to repro their specific scenario.